# OSGi: Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin and Javadoc

Tags: java, osgi, javadoc, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm using the Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin to generate the OSGi metadata.

```
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<extensions>true</extensions>
```

You can configure which packages are exported or you can use the default, which excludes packages such as *.impl.* and *.internal.*.

Is there a way to generate Javadoc only for the exported packages without having to duplicate this information?

**Edit:**

My current approach is that I set the excludePackageNames property (a Maven Javadoc Plugin property) manually and thus duplicate this information:

```
<excludePackageNames>*.internal.*:*.impl.*</excludePackageNames> <!-- used by Javadoc plugin --><!-- TODO: get this from OSGi meta data-->
```

http://sourceforge.net/p/drombler/drombler-oss-parent/ci/default/tree/pom.xml#l64

Comment: maybe you could run the javadoc with the content of the generated jar?

Comment: Could you explain this further? The Javadoc information is not included in the class files, AFAIK.

Comment: I was thinking of extracting the list of included files in the jar and passing this list to the javadoc binary. I am afraid this is the only way to generate the documentation that sticks to the jar content. I cannot see another way.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I'd imagine that one could create a maven plugin that read the generated Manifest.MF and fed that as configuration to the javadoc generator, as @ZNK-M suggested.

Comment: BTW, I thought of another solution yesterday. I was answering a question about ant on so.com. The guy was using the file mapper object. That allows you to transform a file name to another. For Instance convert *.class found in a jar to *.html. You can then pass the result of it to another task. You could generate the whole javadoc and copy only the files that matches the mapper.

Comment: @ChrisDolan yes, this seems the way to go, e.g. a Maven Plugin Goal which populates `excludePackageNames` used by the Javadoc Plugin. maven-bundle-plugin doesn't seem to provide this goal. Is there another plugin? It's strange this is not a common use case.

Comment: @Puce - I think Javadoc is just not as important as it used to be. A pattern I'm seeing instead is source distribution of the API jar. Source is a superset of Javadoc if your IDE is good enough.

Comment: @ChrisDolan can you provide your comment as an answer.In case nobody else comes with a ready solution, I will accept it.

Comment: @ZNK-M the jar also contains the private packages, so analyzing the classes in the jar doesn't help I think.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Maven bundle plugin is based on [bndlib](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd), which has its own plugin model. If a maven plugin model has class visibility to other maven plugins then it is easy to get this information. In the instructions in the pom register a plugin:

```
<instructions>
  <_plugin>com.example.MyPlugin</_plugin>
</instruction>
```

In this bnd plugin, implement the AnalyzerPlugin interface

```
boolean analyzeJar(Analyzer analyzer) throws Exception {
   doJavadoc( analyzer.getExportedPackages().keySet() );
}
```

I am not that familiar with maven plugins, since bnd will do dynamic class loader (yuck), it must be able to see your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure I'm getting everything. Please see my update for my current approach. I think I have to set the excludePackageNames property with information retrieved from bnd in order to integrate with the Maven Javadoc Plugin. I guess your approach would mean not to use the Maven Javadoc Plugin?

Comment: yes, you would have too generate your own javadoc. I guess you could also use the information to set a property that is then used by the javadoc plugin. This answer just provides you with the package names that are actually exported.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best thing would be, if the Maven Bundle Plugin would provide a goal to generate the needed information.

I filed a new issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-4181